# Distribute list elements between two lists equitatively

Tags: algorithm, list, statistics, distribution, backtracking

I have a list with 'n' elements (lets say 10 ie), I want to distribute this elements into two lists, each one balanced with the other by a criteria, evaluating the valour of each element. ie The output should be two lists with 5 elements that are aproximately balanced with each other.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question is too general. Please specify what the criteria is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a quick "solution" by taking the full averagevalue  of the list, then ordering it asc, taking the two highest values for each list and then iterate with the rest. With each iteration I compared the average of the full list with the average of each of the two sublists with the added iteration, each time I put the iteration element in the list wich average was closer to the full average of the list. Keep doing it until the list were full.

I know it is not the best choice but it was good enough for now.

Hope my explanation was clear enough.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ a greedy strategy (I'm not certain this will give you "optimal" results, but it should give you relatively good results at least).

Start by finding the total value of all the elements in your list, V.  The goal is to create two lists each with value about half this amount (ideally as close to 1/2*V as possible).  Start with 3 lists, List_original, List_1, List_2.

Pull off items from List_original (starting with the largest, working your way down to the smallest) and put them into List_1 if and only if adding them to List_1 doesn't cause the total value of List_1 to exceed 1/2*V.  Everything else goes into List_2.

The result will be that List_1 will be at most 1/2*V and List_2 will be at least 1/2*V.  In the event that some subset of your items sums up to exactly 1/2*V then you might get equality.  I haven't tried to prove/disprove this yet.  Depending on how close to balanced your result has to be, this could be good enough (it should at least be very fast).